# Basic-auth is required but the test case passes without authentication in Spring boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, junit5, basic-authentication

I added the Basic AUTH in the Spring boot application, which works perfectly fine. when I write test cases, the test case passes without authentication. I'm surprised how it is possible that the test case runs without Authentication as the application needs authentication.

```
import com.example.userandroles.Entities.Users;
import com.example.userandroles.Service.UserService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import java.util.Base64;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
class UsersControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void addUser() throws Exception {
        Users user = new Users(1L, "Numaira", "Nawaz");
        String jsonRequest = om.writeValueAsString(user);

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/v1/user")
                        .content(jsonRequest)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("useddr:pass".getBytes())))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn();

        //assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    void update() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindUser_Success() throws Exception {
        Long id = 1L;
        Users user = new Users(id, "Numaira", "Nawaz");

        //Mockito.when(userService.findUserById(id)).thenReturn(user);
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/user/{id}", id)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String responseBody = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Users responseUser = om.readValue(responseBody, Users.class);

        assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, result.getResponse().getContentType());
        assertEquals(user.getFirstName(), responseUser.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

And the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:userandroles
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

Why does the test case run without authentication as authentication is required?

Comment: Maybe your security configuration isn't loaded in your tests. Show your entire test class (more precisely, what annotations did you put on top of your test class), your project structure and a minimal version of your security configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
}
```

I got the solution when I removed the setUp method then the authentication works properly.